# Editing what a method returns java

Tags: java, powermock

I ran into problem when I was modding a game. I needed to modify what a method returned without editing that method itself.  I tried doing this with power-mock to no avail.  Does anyone know how to do this with power-mock or any other byte-code manipulation library, or even any standard library? I am willing to use any library, as long as the license allows it to be used for my purposes.

I want to be able to edit the return of static methods, and the return of non static methods on all objects.

Here is what I have tried with power-mock

```
import org.powermock.api.easymock.PowerMock;

import static org.easymock.EasyMock.expect;

public class BeanTest
{
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
   {
      Bean beanMock = PowerMock.createMock(Bean.class);
      expect(beanMock.convert("world")).andReturn("WORLD");
      System.out.println(beanMock.convert("world"));
   }
}

public class Bean
{
   protected String convert(String name) 
   {
      throw new UnsupportedOperationException("not implemented yet");
   }
}
```

Comment: I think you need to put some examples. Are you using a library in your code or are you trying to manipulate compiled bytecode?

Comment: oh sorry here is my example code i posted it above

Answer (score 3):

In java the return type is not part of the method signature so you can do with it whatever you want.

There are two ways of transparently achieving that:

1. Using a Java Dynamic proxy if you can control the injection of this object from whom you are calling the method.
2. Using AspectJ aspect with an around advice you can manipulate code which is out of your control(third party libraries). Using AspectJ trough compile-time weaving or load-time weaving

EDIT:

Using java dynamic proxy(for interfaces) or CGlib(for classes) you can point with an interface to a proxy from which you can intersect the call, do something with it, and delegate it to the real implementation. To achieve that you must be in control of the dependency injection. [Here is a nice explanation](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp08305/index.html).

Example:

```
SomeInterface t = (SomeInterface) Proxy.newProxyInstance(SomeInterface.class.getClassLoader(),
                       new Class<?>[] {SomeInterface.class},
                       new TestInvocationHandler(new TestImpl()));
```

What it does:
The TestInvocationHandler extends the InvocationHandler interface. The TestImpl is a class that implements the SomeInterface. When you call a method from SomeInterface it will end up in TestInvocationHandler. The InvocationHandler has one method invoke which looks like this:

```
public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args);
```

- proxy - reference to the object
- method - the method which is called
- args - the arguments of the method

Using AspectJ you can specify with a pointcut what should be wrapped in an around advice for instance. The advantage of AspectJ is that you can manipulate already compiled code or your own code without any explicit programming.

Example:

```
@Aspect
public class MyAspect {

    @Around("execution(* org.example.yourMethod(..))")
    public Object doNothing(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) {

        // You can call the method or ignore the call and do your logic
        return pjp.proceed();
    }

 }
```

This http://www.hubberspot.com/2012/12/how-to-implement-around-advice-using_12.html is a nice example how to use AspectJ with spring. Maybe it can help you as a starting point.

It's much harder to explain it with CGlib so i exaplain it with Java Dynamic Proxies. For your case

```
 // I suppose Bean implements IBean interface
 IBean beanMock =  (IBean) Proxy.newProxyInstance (
                        IBean.getClass().getClassLoader(),
                        new Class[] { IBean.class },
                        new InvocationHandler() {
                            public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, 
                              Object[] args) throws Throwable {
                                if(method.getName().equals("convert")) {
                                    if(args[0].toString().equals("world")) {
                                        return "WORLD"
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    // Implement default case
                                }
                            }
                        });

 System.out.println(beanMock.convert("world"));
```

Comment: I dont think i fully understand

Comment: you can wrap your method and catch the return value and return whatever you want. Or you can just intersect the call ignore the call to your method and return whatever you want

Comment: what is SomeInterface what do i fill in for that is their any sample code i could use

Comment: This is the interface which has this method you are calling. If some thirdparty method is calling this method you want to change the return value for you have to go with AspectJ. The scope of AOP is huge to explain here. But here you have a really nice explanation about java dynamic proxies: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp08305/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You were pretty close. It looks like you're using the [EasyMock](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/#extension) flavor of [PowerMock](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/). I'm more familiar with the [Mockito](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockitoUsage13) flavor, so I coded up a simple unit test which passes based on what you were attempting:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.mock;
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.when;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class BeanTest {
    @Test
    public void testConvert() throws Exception {
        String worldLower = "world";
        String worldUpper = "WORLD";
        Bean beanMock = mock(Bean.class);
        when(beanMock.convert(worldLower)).thenReturn(worldUpper);
        assertEquals(worldUpper, beanMock.convert(worldLower));
    }
}
```

The only additional change I made was to place `Bean` and `BeanTest` into separate class files.

Comment: Ah, ok. PowerMock / Mockito are designed to be used with unit test frameworks like JUnit or TestNG. Using them outside of a unit test framework may ultimately require more work than an alternate solution would.

Comment: are their any other libraries i could use